# Migrate virtual pageviews to gtag.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js, gtag.js

I'm having problems migrating from analytics.js to gtag.js. The issue is I can't make virtual pageviews work. How to replicate the following analytics.js code in gtag.js?

```
ga('set', 'page', path);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This code is in the **a** tag's onclick event.

This is a single page website which doesn't change the url when you click links.

Comment: Well you didn’t show how you are trying to send using gtag.  So [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration) is how to switch from ga to gtag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example code:

```
ga('set', 'page', path);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

would become:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', {'page_path': path});
```

Where `'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1'` would be your google analytics tracking id.

Explained [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications#tracking_virtual_pageviews).

Comment: After replacing the code, I have been receiving 404 alerts from Search Console. The virtual pages that I have created in the Analytics code actually don't exist, I just created them to organize my GA reports. Thefore Search Console should not request these virtual pages. Ara you having the same issue?

Comment: Would I need to resend custom parameters every time?